# How to provide create_instance access to a group in filenet?

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet

I have added the group in the securities tab of the document class and gave all the necessary permissions. However when trying to create a document within the documentClass I get :

```
FNRCE0001E: E_ACCESS_DENIED: The requester has insufficient access rights to perform the requested operation.
```

The user I'm using to add a document to the document class, belongs to the group that has been given permission to.

NOTE that this works in 5.2.1 version. It fails to work only in the 5.5 version of filenet. The user does belong to the group to which permission is granted.

Comment: what level of access does the group have?

Comment: also how do you add a document, the problem could for instance also be on an entry template or folder access. To create a class instance I think it should at least have view props and create instance on the class definition